# What does "difficult people" mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

I am a native Persian speaker, and I'm wondering what "difficult people" exactly means. In Persian, someone who works hard is literally called a "difficult worker", and someone who doesn't take work easy is called a "difficult taker". So I'm confused about what an English speaker means when he/she says "difficult people".

Comment: This should be an easy one to check in a dictionary. Google `define difficult` and check the third entry (_of a person_). BTW, someone who works hard is literally called a _hard worker_.

Comment: @alwayslearning +1 for learning me fishing not just giving a fish. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Difficult*, in this case, means [*awkward*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/awkward), or hard to deal with. So, *difficult* people are people who are hard to please, or deal with.

> **awkward** (adjective​)
>
> difficult to use, do, or deal with:
>
> - He's an awkward customer (= a difficult person to deal with).

Cambridge Dictionary